# Monitor user actions in ActiveX controls inside IE

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, bho

I have a task to log all user actions in third-party ActiveX controls inside IE. The actions are typing symbols into text boxes, clicking on buttons etc.
So I created a BHO and found an IHTMLElement with the given classid.
What are the next steps for this task solving?
I use C#.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX controls are hosted in Object elements.  You can use the IE DOM apis to get to the Object element, but beyond that layer it becomes opaque to you.  Unless the ActiveX control itself exposes some sort of automation, it is a native code black box.

There are ways of intercepting clicks and key presses in native controls, mostly using subclassing or hooks.  You can use spy++ to inspect the window hierarchy and go looking for those windows using whatever the managed equivalent of [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is.

Answer (score 0):

As jeffamaphone said, Spy++ is capable of capturing the content of text boxes. To do this, Spy++ is actually injecting its own DLL (spyxxhk.dll) into IE in order to be capable to retrieve the content of controls (this is the reason why is requesting Administrative permission when starting). Once injected in the IE process, it is capable to hook any DLL (aka. ActiveX controls) present in the IE process.

To perform the same type of actions (capturing, logging, etc..), you "just" need to develop your own injection engine and register it in order to be automatically started when IE starts. There are many information in the web related to these injection mechanisms. Here a [url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed) to start with.